# Error encountered while developing vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode dev install environment error

node :18.17.0;

os: win10;

yarn:1.2;

i follow this document,but when i run `npm config set msvs_version {visual studio version}`

npm ERR! `msvs_version` is not a valid npm option

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0vml.png)

Comment: are you using nvm or nvs? also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541